# Slick 3 join query one to many relationship

Tags: database, scala, slick, slick-3.0

Imagine the following relation

One book consists of many chapters, a chapter belongs to exactly one book. Classical one to many relation.

I modeled it as this:

```
case class Book(id: Option[Long] = None, order: Long, val title: String)

class Books(tag: Tag) extends Table[Book](tag, "books")
{
  def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def order = column[Long]("order")
  def title = column[String]("title")

  def * = (id, order, title) <> (Book.tupled, Book.unapply)
  def uniqueOrder = index("order", order, unique = true)

  def chapters: Query[Chapters, Chapter, Seq] = Chapters.all.filter(_.bookID === id)
}

object Books
{
  lazy val all = TableQuery[Books]
  val findById = Compiled {id: Rep[Long] => all.filter(_.id === id)}

  def add(order: Long, title: String) = all += new Book(None, order, title)
  def delete(id: Long) = all.filter(_.id === id).delete

//  def withChapters(q: Query[Books, Book, Seq]) = q.join(Chapters.all).on(_.id === _.bookID)

  val withChapters = for
  {
    (Books, Chapters) <- all join Chapters.all on (_.id === _.bookID)
  } yield(Books, Chapters)
}

case class Chapter(id: Option[Long] = None, bookID: Long, order: Long, val title: String)

class Chapters(tag: Tag) extends Table[Chapter](tag, "chapters")
{
  def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def bookID = column[Long]("book_id")
  def order = column[Long]("order")
  def title = column[String]("title")

  def * = (id, bookID, order, title) <> (Chapter.tupled, Chapter.unapply)
  def uniqueOrder = index("order", order, unique = true)

  def bookFK = foreignKey("book_fk", bookID, Books.all)(_.id.get, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Restrict)
}

object Chapters
{
  lazy val all = TableQuery[Chapters]
  val findById = Compiled {id: Rep[Long] => all.filter(_.id === id)}

  def add(bookId: Long, order: Long, title: String) = all += new Chapter(None, bookId, order, title)
  def delete(id: Long) = all.filter(_.id === id).delete
}
```

**Now what I want to do:**

*I want to query all or a specific book (by id) **with all their chapters***

Translated to plain SQL, something like:

`SELECT * FROM books b JOIN chapters c ON books.id == c.book_id WHERE books.id = 10`

but in Slick I can't really get this whole thing to work.

What I tried:

```
object Books
{
    //...
    def withChapters(q: Query[Books, Book, Seq]) = q.join(Chapters.all).on(_.id === _.bookID)
}
```

as well as:

```
object Books
{
    //...
    val withChapters = for
    {
        (Books, Chapters) <- all join Chapters.all on (_.id === _.bookID)
    } yield(Books, Chapters)
}
```

but to no avail. (I use ScalaTest and I get an empty result (for `def withChapters(...)`) or another exception for the `val withChapters = for...`)

How to go on about this? I tried to keep to the documentation, but I'm doing something wrong obviously.

**Also:** Is there an easy way to see the actual query as a String? I only found `query.selectStatement` and the like, but that's not available for my joined query. Would be great for debugging to see if the actual query was wrong.

**edit:** My test looks like this:

```
class BookWithChapters extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures with BeforeAndAfter
{
  val db = Database.forConfig("db.test.h2")

  private val books = Books.all
  private val chapters = Chapters.all

  before { db.run(setup) }
  after {db.run(tearDown)}

  val setup = DBIO.seq(
    (books.schema).create,
    (chapters.schema).create
  )

  val tearDown = DBIO.seq(
    (books.schema).drop,
    (chapters.schema).drop
  )

  "Books" should "consist of chapters" in
  {
    db.run(
      DBIO.seq
      (
        Books.add(0, "Book #1"),
        Chapters.add(0, 0, "Chapter #1")
      )
    )

    //whenReady(db.run(Books.withChapters(books).result)) {
    whenReady(db.run(Books.withChapters(1).result)) {
    result => {
      //  result should have length 1
        print(result(0)._1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

like this I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I used this as my method:

```
object Books
{
      def withChapters(id: Long) = Books.all.filter(_.id === id) join Chapters.all on (_.id === _.bookID)
}
```

also:

`logback.xml` looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement" level="DEBUG/>
</configuration>
```

Where can I see the logs? Or what else do I have to do to see them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate your query...

```
SELECT * FROM books b JOIN chapters c ON books.id == c.book_id WHERE books.id = 10
```

...to Slick we can `filter` the `books`:

```
val bookTenChapters = 
  Books.all.filter(_.id === 10L) join Chapters.all on (_.id === _.bookID)
```

This will give you a query that returns `Seq[(Books, Chapters)]`.  If you want to select different books, you can use a different filter expression.

Alternatively, you may prefer to filter on the join:

```
val everything = 
   Books.all join Chapters.all on (_.id === _.bookID)

val bookTenChapters = 
  everything.filter { case (book, chapter) => book.id === 10L }
```

That will probably be closer to your join.  Check the SQL generated with the database you use to see which you prefer.

You can log the query by creating a `src/main/resources/logback.xml` file and set:

```
 <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement" level="DEBUG"/>
```

I have an [example project with logging set up](https://github.com/underscoreio/essential-slick-code).  You will need to change `INFO` to `DEBUG` in the xml file in, e.g., the chapter-01 folder.

Comment: I created the .xml file under `res/main` and it is found, but where is the log? Should it go to the console? I tried with `info` instead, but I only get the exception, no query-string. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Also, thanks but it's not working for me and I'm not sure why. I updated my question.

Comment: You'll need an "appender" in your XML configuration, and also a logging library in your build.xml.  This gist gives an SBT dependency and a complete logging configuration that should work for you: https://gist.github.com/d6y/fdc780164c044460217b

Comment: Thanks I had exactly that (with version 1.1.3 for logback) already (taken from your example project ;)), but sbt kept complaining that the root wasn't allowed. Now, for whatever reason (I didn't change anything) it works -.-. Thanks a lot! Still no luck with the query tho

Comment: It looks like your test doesn't Await the insert of the two test records? Is that the problem you have, or is it something else that's not working?

Comment: I do the same with Books alone and there it works. Of course I only add Books there, no Chapters. (same setup tho)

Comment: If I disable the logger, everything works. With the logger the BooksTest (without chapters) doesn't work either. But without the logger the BooksWithChapters-Test works like a charm too (and has the right results!) So the logger is somehow interfering with the process. Maybe it's not thread-safe?

Comment: The logger may introduce some timing differences, but I suspect the problem is that some of the futures in your code are completing before others. The order may not be what you expect. I suggest: 1. combining your test into a single action (I've tried to put a rough example here: https://gist.github.com/d6y/6579cb2544caf5466bb6) ; 2. You may also need to await your `before` method, to ensure the tables exist before your test is run.

Comment: Sounds strange, because without the logger the tests *always* run, so no await is required there.